# I cannot log out from the web app while I can using localhost

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0

This is my domain http://congregation.blue-world.pl:

When I test it on localhost it works pretty fine, when I press logout it redirects me to the login and it is good. But when I push the app on the server, it doesn't work there. Why? What makes the difference?

Every time when I tap logout, it moves to the login, but then again redirect me to the admin. Why? On localhost it doesn't work like this.

I have files:

**index.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();

$login = isset($_POST['login']) ? strip_tags($_POST['login']) : false;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? strip_tags($_POST['email']) : false;
$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? strip_tags($_POST['url']) : false;
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? strip_tags($_POST['id']) : false;
$logout = isset($_GET['logout']) ?  strip_tags($_GET['logout']) : false;

if ($login != false && $email != false && $id != false) {
    $_SESSION['log'] = true;
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['url'] = $url;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
}

if (empty($_SESSION['log']) || $logout == 'logout') {
    $_SESSION['log'] = false;
    unset($_SESSION['log']);
    include('login.php');
} else {
    include('admin.php');
}
```

and two other php files, they are actually html files: **login.php, admin.php**.

I simply need to have such view after tap logout:

[image]

and content when I log in:

[image]

Comment: Also if its including login.php ... whats in login.php that may cause a redirect? Need that code.

Comment: please, look at that link on github: https://github.com/kunass2/oauthexample

Comment: @IncredibleHat any ideas?